# Find $\frac{dY}{dX}, Y=(X')^{2}B$ matrix derivative

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product, vectorization

I have the following problem:

> Find the matrix derivative $\frac{dY}{dX}$, where $Y=(X')^2B$, matrix $X$ is $p \times q$ and $B$ is a given matrix.

---

I have gotten this far:

By matrix derivative definition we can write:

$$
\frac{dY}{dX} =\frac{d}{dvec'X} \otimes vec(Y)= \frac{d}{dvec'X} \otimes vec((X')^2B)
$$

Using the vec property (v)

$$
vec(ABC) = (C'\otimes A)vec(B)
$$

We can write the element $vec((X')^2B) = vec(X'X'B)\underbrace{=}_{(v)} (B'\otimes X')vec(X')$

so we get

$$
\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{d}{dvec'X} \otimes \Big[(B'\otimes X')vec(X')\Big]
$$
Using the Kroenecker product property
$$
(A\otimes C)\cdot (B\otimes D) = (AB)\otimes(CD)
$$
we can write

$$
1\cdot \frac{d}{dvec'X}  \otimes \Big[(B'\otimes X')vec(X')\Big] = \Big[1\otimes (B'\otimes X')\Big]\Big[\frac{d}{dvec'X} \otimes vec(X')\Big] = \Big[B'\otimes X'\Big]\Big[\frac{d}{dvec'X} \otimes vec(X')\Big]
$$

So I feel like I am almost there, but I don't get the concept of the matrix differentiation and notation and the difference between $vec'X$ and $vec(X')$. I feel like we can somehow cancel out the last product...

Any tips appericated!

Comment: What is $X'$? If you mean the transpose then $(X')^2$ is inconsistent with the assumption that $X$ is arbitrary rectangular $p\times q$, it would necessarily need to be a square matrix in this case. Do you maybe mean $X^T X$ or $X X^T$ instead?

Comment: Yes. It's a different notation for transpose. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: But then again, when you write $(X')^2$ you are trying to multiply a $q\times p$ matrix with a $q\times p$ matrix, which does not work, except when $p=q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't apply vectorization too early in the process.

The first step is to calculate the *differential* of your function.
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= X^TX^TB \\
dY &= \color{red}{dX^T}X^TB + X^T\color{red}{dX^T}B \\
}$$
The second step is vectorization.
$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{vec}(dY)
 &= \left((X^TB)^T\otimes I\right)\operatorname{vec}(dX^T)
  + \left(B^T\otimes X^T\right)\operatorname{vec}(dX^T) \\
 &= \left(B^TX\otimes I + B^T\otimes X^T\right)K\operatorname{vec}(dX) \\
}$$
where $K$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with Kronecker products, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{vec}(A^T) &= K\operatorname{vec}(A) \\
}$$
Now it's a simple matter to identify the gradient as 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\operatorname{vec}(Y)}{\partial\operatorname{vec}(X)}
 &= \left(B^TX\otimes I + B^T\otimes X^T\right)K \\
}$$